# How to convert gfs file and log file to rosbag file?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the data set I need on the following website, but I do not know the meaning of each file and how to use these files. The address of the website is as follows

[link text](http://www.ipb.uni-bonn.de/datasets/)

The problems expected to be solved are：

1. What do. log and. gfs files represent？
2. How to convert these files to rosbag files？
3. Do these files contain information about the true trajectory of the robot?

I hope someone can help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406506/how-to-convert-gfs-file-and-log-file-to-rosbag-file?/) by [wugeshenhuaking](https://answers.ros.org/users/117137/wugeshenhuaking/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2022-09-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-09-17**:
This sound very much like a homework assignment.

**Comment by [wugeshenhuaking](https://answers.ros.org/users/117137/wugeshenhuaking/) on 2022-09-18**:
@Mike Scheutzow  This is not an assignment. This is the data set about the 2D laser I searched on the Internet. Because I used to run the gmapping algorithm with data in rosbag format, but I found these datasets in some papers, I don't know how to convert these files to files in rosbag format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These files were created by the Carmen "Robot Navigation Toolkit" project. They are compressed ascii files.

The Carmen web site: http://carmen.sourceforge.net/

Info about the Carmen "log" file format: http://carmen.sourceforge.net/logger_playback.html

The Carmen API to read log files: http://carmen.sourceforge.net/doc/group__logger.html

Data Sets: http://radish.sourceforge.net/

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1